Is there an easier way to create contacts using an iPhone?
Why is it so labor intensive to create a new contact in iPhone? I think I missing an easier way to do it?
(pending adding photos to the below)

In messages click phone number at top of conversation.
Click "info"
Chick "Create New Contact"
Fill in Name
Click "Photos"
Click "Albums"
Search for photo they sent you. This could take a long-time depending on the timestamp of the photo they sent you.
Click "Done"
Click "Continue" (weird cropping force-question)
Click "Continue" (weird cropping force-question) (used to make you select a filter)
Click "Done"

If at any point you back out of the app during this process you will lose all your progress.
Desire: I want to be able to simply click the photograph I was sent as a text message and say, "assign photo to this contact". That would only be two buttons. Optionally I could fill in first and last name.
I make a lot of new contacts every week and this process is tedious. Any tips (:

I don't think you need to add photos - it would make the post overly long.

Good call – I will not add photos. Though this points out the issue with creating a new contact. Should only take 2-3 screenshots, but instead would take 10+ screenshots to show the process from start-to-finish.
